# "План дворца несёт в себе исполнение оной идеи"? Ничего?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

> Именно эта постройка* породила целую моду на портики и двухбашенные
>   фасады. Поветрие это в XVIII веке охватит весь мир, включая Россию. А
>   план дворца нашего Павловска несёт в себе исполнение оной идеи
>   палладианства. Её привезёт на нашу землю Чарлз Камерон в XVIII веке. И
>   где бы вы ни повстречали такую реальность – в любом из уголков мира, 
>   – знайте: человек, который её строил – любит Палладио. Он классицист!
>   Передайте ему привет!

- Вилла Барбаро в Мазере. Архитектор – Андреа Палладио. 1560-е.

  ---

Попутный полувопрос:

*...Человек, который её строил – любит Палладио.*

Знаю, что автор будет настаивать на сохранении тире после "строил". Если я закрою запятую, будет перебор знаков?

Comment: Звёздочку надо закрыть. Почему "человек" с большой буквы? Простите уж, что обращаю внимание на мелочи...) Не знаю, надо ли исправлять и как.

Comment: Звездочка - это сноска (к вилле); в цитате прошла, в моём тексте конвертировалась... "Человек" с прописной - потому что это ***абсолютное начало предложения***!

Comment: Во как... Спасибо за пояснение! Даже не слышал про абсолютное начало. А нагуглить хорошо не вышло, определения не нашёл.)

Comment: А проблема в чём? В том, что не просто "оной идеи", а "оной идеи" какой именно? Если да, то согласен, что "оной" означает "вышеназванной, а значит, и не требует пояснения. Но не уверен, что Вас это смущает.

Comment: Смущает: ПЛАН - НЕСЁТ - ИСПОЛНЕНИЕ - ИДЕИ.

Comment: Цитату начинают с прописной (большой) буквы в следующих случаях:
Когда цитирующий начинает цитатой предложение, даже если в цитате опущены начальные слова и она открывается многоточием:
«...Изо всего искусства именно его происхожденье переживается всего непосредственнее, и о нем не приходится строить догадок», — писал Пастернак. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/54-rubric-76

Comment: Может, не план (бумажка, проект), а _планировка_ реально существующего дворца исполнение в себе несёт или ещё как-то воплощает идею, частично или полностью? Или он построен в нарушение некоего проектного плана?

Comment: Спасибо, Галина, очень полезно, буду знать теперь!

Comment: Саш, спасибо: "планировку" сейчас скинем автору!

Comment: Сомнительно сочетание "исполнение идеи": исполняют приказ или нечто строго регламентированное (напр. проект по документации), т. е. "исполнение" требует точности, идею же можно "осуществить", "воплотить" - не требуя от результата точности - на то она и идея, что пребывает в голове и с ней строго ничего не сверить.

Comment: Писал-писал и всё коту под хвост — ошибка при отправке.(( Хотя, может, я ничего умного и не написал. :D

Comment: А мне кажется "несёт исполнение" более странным, чем "исполнение идеи".

Comment: "Оной" еще более неуместно, извините. Стилистика, блин, зело требовательная дама и паки привередливая, в это в натуре должен врубаться каждый пишущий чувак или чика. *Надеюсь, у меня  получилось донести мысль на примере предыдущего предложения*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 А план дворца нашего Павловска несёт в себе исполнение оной 
 идеи палладианства.
```

Всё здесь нормально. Именно план как чертёж. Дело в том,что идея палладианства - постройка дворцов по примеру греческих храмов, она заключается не только в портиках и башнях на фасаде, но и в архитектурной конструкции в форме креста. Когда смотришь на дворец, не замечаешь этого, а на плане-чертеже отчётливо видна форма креста. Павловский дворец - центральное здание, а по бокам узкие галереи, тоже в форме креста. В плане дворца исполнена задуманная идея - крест.

Наш Павловск и наша земля - повтор, конечно, но в первом случае это необходимо, потому что это способ связи предложения с предыдущим с помощью антитезы - там весь мир, а здесь наш Павловск, т. е. русский дворец. Со следующим предложением связывается с помощью лексического повтора. Видимо, автор специально написал "на нашу землю" а не "в Россию". Это художественная особенность.

Вот пунктуацию поправить надо бы, тире многовато. Может, пояснение выделить запятыми, а не тире, если автор настаивает на интонационном тире? Тогда и придаточное можно закрыть запятой.

И где бы вы ни повстречали такую реальность, в любом из уголков мира, знайте: человек, который её строил, – любит Палладио.

Answer (score 1):

**В качестве варианта**:

Именно эта постройка породила целую моду на портики и двухбашенные фасады. Поветрие это в XVIII веке охватит весь мир, включая Россию. А план дворца  Павловска под Петербургом воплощает в себе исполнение оной идеи палладианства. Её привезёт на нашу землю шотландец Чарлз Камерон, приглашенный для оформления Царского Села. И где бы вы ни повстречали такую реальность — в любом из уголков мира, — знайте: человек, который её строил, любит Палладио. Он —  классицист! Передайте ему привет!

Пояснения

1) **Несёт** в себе исполнение оной идеи палладианства — **воплощает** в себе исполнение оной идеи палладианства;

2) Тире нежелательно, так как в этом предложении уже есть вставная конструкция. (Тире (для торжественности) можно поставить после местоимения *он*. Или убрать вставку, заменить ее чем-то.

3) Есть нежелательные повторы: в XVIII веке — 2 раза, нашего Павловска — на нашу землю. Что-то надо изменить.

Comment: Jasmin, автора нельзя переписывать!

Comment: Это просто вариант, как можно убрать повторы. Автор же может как-то иначе изменить текст.